# How you can sort by id with where, and return only the most recent result

Tags: mysql

I could not find this question when I searched for it, so below is my answer with how I did a MySQL query with a `WHERE` statement, and returned only the **last result.** In this case, I sorted by my primary key, named "id."

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE columnname='ColumnEntry' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```